# How to sort array of objects by title if first character is a symbol

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, rest, sorting

I am sorting an array of objects (products) and rendering them into a React functional component.

The products in question come from the dummyjson API
https://dummyjson.com/docs/products

I am trying to implement a sort function to sort them by title in asc order on when fetching the API data with the following line of code:

```
let sortData = data.products.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
    setProducts([...sortData])
```

This works fine and I understand the concept of sorting. However, one of the product titles is "- Daal Masoor 500 grams", meaning it automatically takes first place in the sorted list before numbers and letters due to the "-" character.

How do I handle this and sort it based on the first letter character? Or is it best practice to sort based on the API data no matter what? (and keep it as the first value when sorted).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What about removing all the characters that are not part of the standard alphabet? So changing "- Daal Masoor 500 grams" to "Daal Masoor 500 grams" etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract with a regex the title from the 1rst letter character and sort according to that modified title version. So you won't modify the real title and the sort will be in order ?